# Validation issues with xquery

Tags: xquery

I am developing wrapper API using BPM kind of tool. This wrapper should call another API internally, if the API returns multiple response then I need to loop all the responses and put into the wrapper API in the below structure. I wrote the below logic to read the API response write to wrapper API target structure using XQuery logic, however it has validation issues and the expression editor not providing much details.

```
declare variable $externalApiResponse := $temp.tmp_infaSearchResult ;  

let $targetStructure := object {
  "searchResult": object {
    "totalRecords": xs:double(0),  
    "records": array {}
  }
}

(: Set totalRecords based on the number of responses from the external API :)
let $totalRecords := count($externalApiResponse)
return
if ($totalRecords > 0) then
  (: Loop over each response from the external API :)
  for $response in $externalApiResponse
  return
    (
      (: Create a record for each response :)
      let $record := object {
        "metaData": object {
          "score": xs:double($response/score),
          "businessId": $response/businessId,
          "xrefSourceSystem": $response/xrefSourceSystem,
          "xrefSourcePKey": $response/xrefSourcePKey
        },
        "data": object {
          "name": $response/name,
          "postalAddress": array {
            (
              (: Loop over each address in the response :)
              for $address in $response/postalAddress
              return
                object {
                  "addressLine1": $address/addressLine1,
                  "city": $address/city,
                  "country": object {
                    "Code": $address/country/Code,
                    "Name": $address/country/Name
                  },
                  "postalCode": $address/postalCode
                }
            )
          },
          "taxDetail": array {
            (
              (: Loop over each tax detail in the response :)
              for $taxDetail in $response/taxDetail
              return
                object {
                  "taxNumber": $taxDetail/taxNumber
                }
            )
          }
        }
      }
      return insert into $targetStructure.searchResult.records ( $record )
    )

return $targetStructure
```

Comment: `object { "key": value }` looks like some proprietary variation of the `map { "key": value }` syntax in standard XQuery 3.1. Please indicate what version of XQuery you are using.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank you for your response, the BPM tool supports XQuery verion 3.0

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what this "BPM tool" is, but I do know that the syntax `object{"key":value}` is not defined in XQuery 3.0 or any other version. Perhaps that's the problem, you are using incorrect syntax.